# How to disable customer account in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I want to disable particular customer account in magento store. Any free extension available for disable particular customer account in magento

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this module, it's working.
https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-account-approval

Comment: I add this extension but this not work on my store. I cleared cache

Comment: https://prnt.sc/m8qpkd, Just download module and upload in /app/code folder and apply command :-
php bin/magento setup:upgrade, 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f